# Error message Standard error Shellscript

Tags: shell, if-statement, zip, stderr

i need some help here because i'm not sure if this is right, i have to write a shell script where i zip two text files, and then send a error message to standart  error if the file already exists, also it can't overwrite the existing file

I also need some help with the if's, i tried elseif but didn't work

```
#!/bin/bash

echo " Backup..."

if [ ! -f file_2013.zip ] ; then

  if [ -f file1.txt ] && [ -f file2.txt ] ; then 
      zip -rp file_2013.zip file1.txt file2.txt 

       else 
          echo "File not Found"

else 
    cat file_2013.zip > /dev/stderr
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the `if` statements with the `fi` keyword. See for instance [this](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/bash-if-statement-examples/)